# What is the "LE" prepended earphones im seeing in my bluetooth?

Tags: networking, bluetooth

I am seeing a Bluetooth device with my earphones' name prepended with "LE_" in my Bluetooth available devices.
[image]

1. I could connect with it only if I remove it and then try to connect to it.
2. It disconnects if I put my earphones back in the charging case and then I cannot connect with it again without removing the device and then clicking on it from discovered devices
3. There is a proper "WF_1000XM4" in my available Bluetooth devices as well and that is the one that my earphones are

What is this "LE_WF1000XM4" that I am seeing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's your device in [Bluetooth Low Energy mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy).

You can edit `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and change `ControllerMode` to be `bredr` to disable LE connections, after which it should only look for BR/EDR connections. I have to do this on my Raspberry Pi, which otherwise doesn't like my Bluetooth headphones in LE mode.